# Setting up a dynamic bucketed constraint in MarkLogic for dates

Tags: xquery, marklogic

In my database, I have a path range index on `<date>` that contains xs:dates.

```
<date>2019-01-01</date>
```

I'm trying to set up a faceted constraint with the following buckets:

```
2019 with quarter (2019 Q1 (Jan-Mar), Q2 (April-June) etc)

2018 

2017

2016

2015

etc
```

My issue is, I want to dynamically update the bucket to compute the current year into the quarterly bucket, with the rest of the years following. I have a current bucketed range constraint:

```
<constraint name="date">
    <range type="xs:date" facet="true">
        <path-index>/data/date</path-index>
        <bucket ge="2019-01-01" lt="2019-03-01" name="q1">2019 Q1</bucket>
        <bucket ge="2019-04-01" lt="2019-06-01" name="q2">2019 Q2</bucket>
        <bucket ge="2019-07-01" lt="2019-09-01" name="q3">2019 Q3</bucket>
        <bucket ge="2019-10-01" lt="2019-12-01" name="q4">2019 Q4</bucket>
        <bucket ge="2018-01-01" lt="2019-01-01" name="2018">2018</bucket>
        <bucket ge="2017-01-01" lt="2018-01-01" name="2017">2017</bucket>
        <bucket ge="2016-01-01" lt="2017-01-01" name="2016">2016</bucket>
        <bucket ge="2015-01-01" lt="2016-01-01" name="2015">2015</bucket>
    </range>
</constraint>
```

The issue with the above, is that it manually is setting 2019 to be split up into quarters, but when it turns 2020 and years following, how could I get the bucket to automatically update and only split apart the current year into quarters?

Comment: I think I would use a custom constraint. Have you looked at this section yet? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750

Answer (score 1):

Would computed buckets address the requirement?  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_22725

and

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_91755

Hoping that helps,